# How to properly use ObservableMap in Java

Tags: java, javafx, collections, observable

I'm currently developing a chat application and I want, in my GUI controllers, to have Observables Collections to be able to manage messages that I receive.

So, to be more specific I have this listener where I listen for new messages that comes from the server:

**Listener for new Chats:**

```
class ChatCustomManagerListener {   
   private static HashMap <Chat, ChatCustomMessageListener> chatsTable;

   /*
   * This is the event that gets triggered when new chat is created
   */
   public void chatCreated (Chat newChat) {
       ChatCustomMessageListener listener = new ChatCustomMessageListener();
       newChat.addListener (listener);
       chatsTable.put (newChat, listener);
    }
}
```

**Listener for new Messages:**

```
class ChatCustomMessageListener {
   private List <Message> messagesQueue;

   public ChatCustomMessageListener () {
      //QueuedLinkedList is my extension of LinkedList class
      //add() is made at the tail of List
      //get() returns the head of list
      messagesQueue = new QueuedLinkedList ();
    }
   /*
   * This is the event that gets triggered when a new message is received
   */
    public void processMessage (Chat chat, Message message) {
       messagesQueue.add (message);
    }
}
```

Now, In my GUI Controllers, I want to define an `ObservableMap` to look for `ChatCustomManagerListener.chatsTable` changes and for each `Entry` inside chatsTable, I want to have an `ObservableList` for `ChatCustomMessageListener.messagesQueue`

What I got so far, but not working is this:

```
    class ChatController {
       private ObservableMap  <Chat, ChatCustomMessageListener> chatsObserver;
       private LinkedList <ObservableList <Message>> messagesObservables;
       private LinkedList <List <Message>> messageData;

       private void initObservables () {
          chatsObserver = FXCollections.observableMap (ChatCustomManagerListener.getChats ());

        messageData   = new LinkedList <> ();
        messagesObservables = new LinkedList <> ();

        chatsObserver.forEach ((chat, messageListener) -> {
            messageData.add (messageListener.getMessagesQueue());
        });

        messageData.forEach ((queueOfMessages) -> {
            ObservableList <Message> observer = FXCollections.observableList (queueOfMessages);
            observer.addListener (new ListChangeListener <Message> () {

                @Override
                public void onChanged (javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change <? extends Message> c)                      
                    log.debug ("New message was received");
                }
            });
            messagesObservables.add (observer);
        });

        chatsObserver.addListener (new MapChangeListener <Chat, ChatCustomMessageListener> () {

            @Override
            public void onChanged (
                    javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change <? extends Chat, ? extends ChatCustomMessageListener> change) {
                //define what is done when a new chat is created
                log.debug ("New  chat was created");

            }

        });
}}
```

So what is the right way to define my Observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableMap` can only see changes when they are made through itself. So if you change the backing map you will not be notified about those changes.

You will need to change your `ChatCustomManagerListener` to add chats through the `ObservableMap` object to listen for those changes.

Comment: What if I define my Map inside ChatCustomManagerListener as observable and then get the map inside my controller and define the onChangeListener's comportament here? Is this possible?

Comment: for example in `initComponents` have `ChatCustomManagerListener.getObservableMap().addListener ( new MapChangeListener () {});`

Comment: Yes, that would work. As long as there is no way to edit the original map directly.